# jQuery how to use off() on the closest container of an element

Tags: jquery

I would like to unbind an event on a div that contains a button when this button is clicked
I am using this piece of code but it doesn't seem to work, the event keeps being attached to the button container:

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function(){
        $('body').off('mouseleave',$(this).closest('.button-container'));
});
```

what am I doing wrong?

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/y3a6N/3/

Thanks

Comment: And what's your `on()` look like? What's the HTML look like? Can you post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: We have to see your HTML to know how to help.

Comment: Updated fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/y3a6N/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `.on()` and `.off()` that way.  Your `.on()` code is a delegated handler:

```
$('body').on('hover', '.button-container', function(){
   $(this).append('<p>New text</p>');
});
```

It's an event handler attached to the body object and looking for hover events from any element with class of "button-container".

You cannot then just do `.off()` on one particular element like you are trying to do with this:

```
$('body').off('hover',$(this).closest('.button-container'));
```

That doesn't match the `.on()` signature so there's no matching event handler to remove.  With delegated event handler (like you're using here with `.on()`), it's either all of nothing.  You either remove the entire event handler or not.  You can't tell it to just stop delegating on behalf of only some objects.

If your objects are not dynamic and thus you don't need delegated event handling, you can do this to remove the specific event handler you want to remove:

```
function addText() {
   $(this).append('<p>New text</p>');
}

$('.button-container').on('hover', addText);

$('.button').on('click', function(){
   $(this).closest('.button-container').off('hover', addText);
});
```

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/R2eQx/.

---

Another approach that might be simpler is to just remove the class from the object like this:

```
<div class="button-container active">
    <div class="button" style="border: 1px solid #cc0000">Roll over me to make text appear / Click me to stop making text appear (doesn't work)</div>
</div>

$('body').on('hover', '.active', function(){
   $(this).append('<p>New text</p>');
});

$('body').on('click', '.button', function(){
   $(this).closest(".button-container").removeClass("active");
});
```

And a working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/byFpx/.

This leaves the event handler in place, but just removes the triggering class from the button-container so it won't match the event handler any more.  This makes it easier to make it trigger again by just adding the class back again.

Comment: @Vincent - I added another option at the end of my answer that might be even cleaner.  It just adds/removes a class from the parent.

Comment: wow, your answer really outweighed my expectations, 1000 thanks for you, very helpfull

Comment: @Vincent - Delegated events are very powerful, but slightly confusing in some circumstances so I thought it useful to try to explain what was going on.  Glad you appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of off is wrong. Looking at your old code and your description, I think this is what you trying to achieve:

```
   var handler = function(){
        $(this).append('<p>New text</p>') }
    $('body').on('hover', '.button-container', handler);

    $('body').on('click', '.button', function(){

       $('body').off('hover', ".button-container", handler);
    });
```

This will disable the hover event handler you assigned using the first `.on()`